# Enforcing WorkingPrecision in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, machine-precision

I have a very complicated 2D integral that I need to calculate repeatedly, and I'm trying to speed it up a bit, since at the moment it's taking a couple of days to complete.

One thing I've noticed is that when `NIntegrate` samples the integrand, it sometimes dives into very high precision numbers, even though `WorkingPrecision` is set to `$MachinePrecision`.

Here's a fairly minimal example to demonstrate:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := (result = Exp[Sin[Sqrt[x]]]; Sow[{x, result}]; result)

{result, {samples}} = Reap[NIntegrate[(f[x]), {x, 0, 1}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]]

Tally[Precision /@ samples]
```

The last result is then

```
{{MachinePrecision, 122}, {65.9546, 7}}
```

I suspect that the high-precision is necessary to achieve the requested `PrecisionGoal` or `AccuracyGoal`, but in the case of my real integrand, the underlying dataset simply doesn't have data at that level of precision (it's mostly linear interpolations of experimental data, with some complicated transformations). Since MachinePrecision is much faster than arbitrary precision, I'd rather stick to it if possible.

Interestingly, there doesn't seem to be any particular features at the points that are being focussed on. In the example above, it samples multiple points very close to 0.06, and I can't see any special significance to that part of the function. I have a similar problem with my real integrand.

I've tried setting `$MaxExtraPrecision`, but I'm not sure that it has any impact on `NIntegrate`.

Is there some other way to tell *Mathematica* that it should stick to `$MachinePrecision`?

Comment: Use `N` on `x` inside `f`?

Comment: One can see from `ListPlot[samples[[2 ;;, 1]]]` that after 4 applications of the  `"GlobalAdaptive"` strategy with the `"GaussKronrodRule"`, a different rule or approach is applied to the interval `{0, 1/16}`.  I don't know why `NIntegrate` evaluates the function for `x` near and at the upper end point `1/16` with high precision.  It could be estimating the derivative in order to estimate the error or check for a singularity/oscillatory behavior, maybe.

Comment: There are strategies for [integrating interpolating functions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=integrate+interpolating+function).  Your use-case might be slow for reasons other than a few high-precision evaluations.

Comment: Using N on x inside f changes the precision of the output, but the integration routine continues to request absurdly high-precision x. Changing the integration methods seem to have little effect - even the trapezoidal rule gives this behavior. Even the LocalAdaptive strategy exhibits the same problem. Unfortunately, my real integrand is a lot more than interpolating functions - it contains a mixture of theory and experiment, so there are a few Piecewises and both 1 and 2-D interpolations with Guassian fits for extrapolation - in short, it would be very difficult to handle it in a specific way.

Comment: Why not `f2[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := f[N[x], N[y]]`?  This bumps down the precision before the function is evaluated and it should not take a lot of time.  BTW, the absurdly high precision is `$MachinePrecision + $MaxExtraPrecision`.

Comment: That solution still means that the integrator gets stuck on those few points - even though the integrand is then evaluated at machine precision and always returns the same result. Not an ideal solution, though perhaps good enough. On the other hand, it turns out that the problem is with the Singularity Handler, and if I disable that, I don't get the high-precision problem, although it does get stuck in a different part of the function for some reason. BTW, changing $MaxExtraPrecision has no effect, so far as I can tell. I am continuing to investigate.

Comment: Yes, I suspected it was the singularity handling that was the main issue.  That is common with interpolating functions. Without the actual function, there's a limit to what can be guessed at.  I seemed to get the precision down to [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$MachinePrecision.html) with `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 0}, <integral>]` -- it still uses arbitrary precision which is usually much slower than [`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MachinePrecision.html).